# Crash dump in .net not writing anything to the file?

Tags: c#

I am using the below article's code to write the crash dump. But i am unable to find anything in the file. File is created but blank.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/6c8d3529-a493-49b9-93d7-07a3a2d715dc

And i have used the above code like this.

```
private void btnCrash_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     throw new Exception("2");
}
```

In program.cs the below code is present. Everything is running fine but unable to see anything in the crash dump file.

```
static void Main()
{
   Application.EnableVisualStyles();
   Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
   AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
   currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
   Application.Run(new Form1());
}

static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    String fileToDump = @"C:\CrashDumpDemo\test.txt";
    MiniDumpDemo.MiniDumpToFile(fileToDump);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to invoke `MiniDumpDemo.MiniDumpToFile(fileToDump);` directly in the button handler? Step through it in debugger?

Comment: 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in CrashDumpDemo.exe is raised when i called from button handler

Comment: Do you have a 64 bit version of Windows? Which platform you project is targeted at? This error may be because you are using ANY CPU platform on 64 bit windows, and when it is run, it runs as 64 bit process, but can`t find appropriate 64 bit dbghelp.dll. Try setting target platform to x86.

Comment: i tried that , but still that problem exists and i am using it in windows XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the proper version of the dbghelp.dll . It seems i had old version 5.x.x.x and used latest 6.x.x.x. So everything is fine.